# Trouble with hline indices not changing when running boxplots/horizontal lines in a loop

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have searched a long time for the solution for this to no avail. I am graphing boxplots with some horizontal lines accross in ggplot2 in a loop. I figured out to map the line aesthetics setting "colour" as the name I want in the legend to get a legend for the lines as well as boxplots. However, the line indices values seem to not update and what is drawn is the same line values on all the plots, specifically the values from the last item in the loop.

I reproduced the problem with the iris dataset as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
liris<-gather(iris,"Param","Value",1:4)
liris<-as.data.frame(liris)

indices<-unique(liris$Param)
plot_list<-list()
for (i in indices) {
sub<-filter(liris,Param==i)

min<-min(sub$Value)
max<-max(sub$Value)

g<-ggplot(sub,aes(x=Param,y=Value,fill=Param))
g<-g+geom_boxplot()
g<-g+facet_wrap(~Species)
g<-g+geom_hline(aes(yintercept=min,colour="Min Sepal Length"),linetype="dashed",show_guide=TRUE)
g<-g+geom_hline(aes(yintercept=max,colour="Max Sepal Length"),linetype="dashed",show_guide=TRUE)
g<-g+theme()+scale_color_manual(values=c("blue","black"))
g<-g+theme(legend.position="bottom")+guides(colour=guide_legend(title=NULL))
g<-g+theme(legend.position="bottom")+guides(fill=guide_legend(title=NULL))
g<-g+theme(legend.box="horizontal")

plot_list[[i]] = g

}

pdf("TEST.pdf",height = 8.5, width = 11,onefile=TRUE,paper="special")
for (i in indices) {
print(plot_list[[i]])
}
dev.off()
```

This produces the plots with a nice legend, but the horizontal lines are all the same value. I can tell it is something with mapping the line aesthetics with my limited experience with ggplot2. If I do not map them and do this the line values change correctly, but no legend.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)    
liris<-gather(iris,"Param","Value",1:4)
liris<-as.data.frame(liris)

indices<-unique(liris$Param)
plot_list<-list()
for (i in indices) {
sub<-filter(liris,Param==i)

min<-min(sub$Value)
max<-max(sub$Value)

g<-ggplot(sub,aes(x=Param,y=Value,fill=Param))
g<-g+geom_boxplot()
g<-g+facet_wrap(~Species)
g<-g+geom_hline(yintercept=min,colour="black",linetype="dashed",show_guide=TRUE)
g<-g+geom_hline(yintercept=max,colour="blue",linetype="dashed",show_guide=TRUE)
g<-g+theme(legend.position="bottom")+guides(colour=guide_legend(title=NULL))
g<-g+theme(legend.position="bottom")+guides(fill=guide_legend(title=NULL))
g<-g+theme(legend.box="horizontal")

plot_list[[i]] = g

}

pdf("TEST2.pdf",height = 8.5, width = 11,onefile=TRUE,paper="special")
for (i in indices) {
print(plot_list[[i]])
}
dev.off()
```

Any feedback and thoughts rectify this would be very welcome. Thanks much.

Answer (score 3):

I got a little carried away with formatting the plot, but here is a a solution that should give you the changing min and max values you were looking for. Keep in mind that because of geom_boxplot() is setting the xlims(), the dashed lines always frame the the plot range, but the scale values are fluctuating.

```
indices<-unique(liris$Param)
plot_list<-list()
for (i in indices) {
    sub <- filter(liris,Param==i)
    #min <- min(sub$Value)
    #max <- max(sub$Value)

    g <- ggplot(sub,aes(x=Param,y=Value)) +
        geom_boxplot(fill = "green", alpha = .5) +
        facet_wrap(~Species) +
        geom_hline(aes(yintercept=min(Value),colour="Max"),linetype="dashed",show.legend=TRUE) +
        geom_hline(aes(yintercept=max(Value),colour="Min"),linetype="dashed",show.legend=TRUE) + 
        scale_color_manual(values=c("blue","red")) +
        theme_bw() +
        theme(legend.position="bottom")+guides(colour=guide_legend(title=NULL)) +
        theme(legend.position="bottom")+guides(fill=guide_legend(title=NULL)) +
        theme(legend.box="horizontal") +
        labs(title = paste0(i, " Facetted by Species"), x = "", y = "cm")

    plot_list[[i]] <- g
}
pdf("TEST2.pdf",height = 8.5, width = 11,onefile=TRUE,paper="special")
for (i in plot_list) {
    print(i)
}
dev.off()
```

Really all you need to to do is to call min(Value) and max(Value) functions on the fly inside of their respective geom_hline()s instead of before the plot build. Any elements inside of aes() are supposed to come from the data being sourced for the plot (liris), not just variables in your environment (min, max)

[image]

Comment: Thanks Nathan Day so much, it was "Really all you need to to do is to call min(Value) and max(Value) functions on the fly inside of their respective geom_hline()s instead of before the plot build. Any elements inside of aes() are supposed to come from the data being sourced for the plot (liris), not just variables in your environment (min, max)" that clicked for me. I moved my yintercept values into the aes of the lines and it worked perfectly. Correct hlines and all my legends. Thanks for the formatting cleanup too! I am just learning.

Comment: Happy to help! ggplot2 is an awesome tool to learn. I've found 99% of all the ggplot errors I get are because of some aes() issue too. Good luck coding, and feel free to holler if you have any more problems that you get hung up on.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a possible solution that shows a common method of including auxiliary or summary data in `ggplot2`. It is not an exact solution to your question, but that has been provided by @Nathan Day.

Below, I create a second data.frame that contains the summary data (minimum and maximum values). A key concept is that the purpose of `aes()` is to create an association between a *column* of a data.frame and a visual feature of the plot. Inside the `geom_hline()` call, I use `aes()` to map the `StatValue` column to the `yintercept` feature, and the `SummaryStatistic` column is associated with the `colour` feature. Note that `linetype` is used *outside* of `aes()`, because we want all 8 hlines to have the same linetype, regardless of any information in the summary data columns.

```
# Create separate data.frame containing summary data.
summary_data <- liris %>%
                group_by(Param) %>%
                summarise(Maximum=max(Value), Minimum=min(Value)) %>%
                gather(key=SummaryStatistic, value=StatisticValue, -Param)
summary_data
#          Param SummaryStatistic StatisticValue
#          (chr)            (chr)          (dbl)
# 1 Petal.Length          Maximum            6.9
# 2  Petal.Width          Maximum            2.5
# 3 Sepal.Length          Maximum            7.9
# 4  Sepal.Width          Maximum            4.4
# 5 Petal.Length          Minimum            1.0
# 6  Petal.Width          Minimum            0.1
# 7 Sepal.Length          Minimum            4.3
# 8  Sepal.Width          Minimum            2.0

# Create named vector, for use with manual color scales.
summary_colors = c(Maximum="darkorange", Minimum="royalblue")

p = ggplot(liris, aes(x=Species, y=Value)) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    geom_hline(data=summary_data,
               aes(yintercept=StatisticValue, colour=SummaryStatistic),
               linetype="dashed", size=1.6) +
    scale_colour_manual(values=summary_colors) +
    facet_grid(. ~ Param)
```

[image]